# Segmentation Fault While Manipulating String

Tags: c, cs50, undefined-behavior, c-strings, null-pointer

I'm trying to create a Ceasar Cipher. For this test, I used a key of 1 and plain text of "hello." When doing so, I get the error message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I know this means I am trying to access an illegal memory location, and it's happening while calling the "encrypt" function, but that's all I know.

[Depiction of the error I'm getting while debugging.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhRBY.png)

And here is my code.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isValidKey(string);
string encrypt(string, int);

string c;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || isValidKey(argv[1]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Useage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 0;
    }
    string p = get_string("plaintext: ");
    c = encrypt(p, atoi(argv[1]));
    printf("%s", c);
    return 0;
}

bool isValidKey(string key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(key[i]) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

string encrypt(string plain, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plain); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plain[i]) != 0)
        {
            if (islower(plain[i]) != 0)
            {
                c[i] = ((plain[i] - 97 + k) % 26) + 97;
            }
            else
            {
                c[i] = ((plain[i] - 65 + k) % 26) + 65;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: `string c;` declares a pointer, it doesn't allocate any memory for it.

Comment: Instead of `97`, write `'a'`.  Similarly for 65.  The magic number `26` should be replaced with something like `SIZE_OF_ALPHABET` or `'z' - 'a' + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `c`.

```
string encrypt(string plain, int k)
{
    c = malloc(strlen(plain) + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plain); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plain[i]) != 0)
        {
            if (islower(plain[i]) != 0)
            {
                c[i] = ((plain[i] - 97 + k) % 26) + 97;
            }
            else
            {
                c[i] = ((plain[i] - 65 + k) % 26) + 65;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

And in `main()` you should add `free(c);` before `return 0;`

Comment: You are not terminating `c`.

Comment: I was just adding that

Comment: How do you know `string` is a typedef for `char *`?

Comment: Because I know it's a typedef in `cs50.h`.

Comment: I really don't understand how teaching C with non standard headers and libraries is helpful.

Comment: @Irelia In many cases it allows you to focus on the algorithms without having to deal with gory details of C. E.g. providing functions like `get_string()` allows you to avoid spending time dealing with I/O so you can get to the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `c` declared in the file scope

```
string c;
```

is a null pointer. The above declaration is equivalent to

```
char *c;
```

or in fact to

```
char *c = NULL;
```

So using the null pointer within the function `encrypt` like

```
c[i] = ((plain[i] - 97 + k) % 26) + 97;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also it is a bad idea when a function like `encrypt` depends on a global variable.

Also using magic numbers like for example `97` makes the program unclear.

As the function parameter does not have the qualifier `const` then it will be logical to convert the passed string in place.

Pay attention to that the user can pass a very big integer value as a key. In this case your function will invoke undefined behavior.

So the function can look like

```
string encrypt( string plain, int k)
{
    k = k % 26;

    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( plain ); i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )plain[i] ) )
        {
            if ( islower( plain[i] ) )
            {
                plain[i] = ( plain[i] - 'a' + k ) % 26 + 'a';
            }
            else
            {
                plain[i] = ( plain[i] - 'A' + k ) % 26 + 'A';
            }
        }
    }

    return plain;
}
```

The variable `c` should be removed and in main it is enough to write

```
string p = get_string( "plaintext: " );
puts( encrypt( p, atoi( argv[1] ) ) );
```